# Customizar rutas de Login en Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hola tengo un problema con el enrutado de Login con el metodo php artisan make:auth que te genera todo lo que se necesita
Desde vamos me costo bastante unir el proyecto que estaba haciendo a este login y sus vistas. Pero no me deja cambiar la ruta prefedinida a una que yo quiera

Asi vienen por defecto:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');

Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Asi customizo

```
Route::get('admin/auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');

Route::post('admin/auth/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');

Route::post('admin/auth/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

LoginController.php

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected $redirectTo = '/';


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.login'); //tambien cambie de dir la carp auth
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    //return view('inicio');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Cuando entro a la ruta del login, y me logueo
me tira este error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:...

Comment: Si entiendo bien, el error aparece una vez haces clic en el botón "Ingresar" ? De ser así, puedes mostrarnos la vista `admin.auth.login` ?

Comment: @Shaz. Solucionado. El hecho si de que pidas ver el .blade me di cuenta de que no  lo habia modificado al por default. Igual edito mi primer mensaje con la solucion por si a alguien le sirve

Comment: Por favor agrega la solución como respuesta o elimina la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente me faltó corregir el form del `login.blade.php` por el default que provee Laravel. Al colocar la URL correcta, funciona según lo esperado.

```
form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('admin/auth/login') }}"> {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Recordar, que tambien esta el form del Logout que sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Puedes pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: La forma de indicar que has encontrado un respuesta/solución a tu consulta, es aceptando la respuesta.

Comment: Lo intente hacer. pero me dice que tengo q esperar 2 dias para aceptar mi respuesta. sera por que soy nuevo? de cualquier forma voy a revisar los links

Comment: Es para para disuadirte de autocontestarte compulsivamente. Recuerda volver en 2 días.